# What percentage of refugees from Yugoslavia returned home after the war had ended?

Tags: yugoslavia

I'm trying to understand the process of how Yugoslav refugees returned to their home countries after the end of the [Yugoslav wars, 1991-2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugoslav_Wars). How many refugees returned to their home countries voluntarily and how many of them had to be forcibly repatriated? I am only interested in refugees who left the territories of former Yugoslavia, and not internally displaced people in Slovenia or other places which were mostly secure from the war.

I've found an [interesting paper](https://works.swarthmore.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1011&context=swarthmoreirjournal) that answered this for Germany and Austria, but not for other countries:

> While the federal government maintained a policy of voluntary return, more
> German states were deciding to forcibly
> repatriate Bosnian refugees (though not all
> agreed on when it would be appropriate
> to do so). By the end of the 1990s, Germany thus repatriated 347,419 individuals
> to Bosnia, almost 70% of total Bosnian
> repatriations in Europe.

Comment: Note that the approach in Austria was almost the opposite of that in Germany, in that in Austria Bosnians were basically allowed to stay, subject to some common-sense conditions.